# Conversion from string "5:53:10 PM" to type 'Integer' is not valid

Tags: sql, vb.net, ado.net

I WANT TO GET THE TIME DIFF BETWEEN dr(3) and dr(4)

```
Sub workinghours()
    cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dtrtable WHERE EmployeeID = '" & Me.TextBox3.Text & "' AND TimeOUT is not NULL", con)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While dr.Read
        gettimein = dr(3)
        gettimeout = dr(4)

        While gettimein < gettimeout
            gethours = gethours + 1
            gettimein = gettimein + 1
        End While
        gettimein = Nothing
        gettimeout = Nothing
    End While
    dr.Close()
    Me.TextBox8.Text = gethours
    gethours = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: And what is surprising?  `5:53:10 PM` is not a valid integer value.

Comment: What should be your output?.Mention expected output in the question.

Comment: Do you want to change the laws of programming?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `TimeSpan` class for this, you just need to strip off the `AM/PM` part.

```
Dim ts1 = TimeSpan.Parse(dr(3).ToString.Replace(" AM", "").Replace(" PM", ""))
Dim ts2 = TimeSpan.Parse(dr(4).ToString.Replace(" AM", "").Replace(" PM", ""))

If ts1 > ts2 Then 
'do something
End If
```

Answer (score -1):

i already solved it, now my problem is getting the Overtime if the timediff is > 8. Here's my code..

```
  
Sub eto()
        cmd = New SqlCommand("select * from dtrtable where EmployeeID = '" & Me.TextBox3.Text & "'AND TimeOUT is not NULL ", con)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While dr.Read
            gethours = DateDiff(DateInterval.Hour, dr(3), dr(4))
            While dr.Read
                gethours = gethours + DateDiff(DateInterval.Hour, dr(3), dr(4))
            End While
        End While
        dr.Close()
        Me.TextBox9.Text = getothours
        Me.TextBox8.Text = gethours
    End Sub
```